# regular expression to remove the first word of each line

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a regular expression that grabs the first word (including possible leading white space) of each line.  Here it is:

```
/^([\s]+[\S]*).*$/\1//
```

This code does not seem to be working (see http://regexr.com?34o6m).  The code is supposed to

1. Begin at the start of the line
2. Create a capturing group where it places the first word (with possible leading white space)
3. Grab the rest of the line
4. Substitute the entire line with just the inside of the first capturing group

I tried another version also:

```
/\S(?<=\s).*^//
```

It looks like this one fails too (http://regexr.com?34o6s).  The goal here was to

1. Find the first non-whitespace character.
2. Look behind to make sure it has a whitespace character behind it (i.e. not the first letter of the line).
3. Grab the rest of the line.
4. Erase everything the expression just grabbed.

Any insight to what is going wrong would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: If the leading whitespace is only possible, you should have an asterisk, not a plus, after the first [\s]

Comment: Maybe use the [word boundary thingy](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml), something like: /^([\s]*.?[\b]).*/ (not tested, and I doubt it'll work as is, but I'll keep working on it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up your `+` and `*`.

```
/^([\s]*[\S]+).*$/\1/
```

This means zero or more spaces followed by one or more non-spaces.

You might also want to use `$1` instead of `\1`:

```
/^([\s]*[\S]+).*$/$1/
```

Comment: This still doesn't appear to be working (http://regexr.com?34o6v).  Maybe it's just this gkskinner.com that's messing up?

Comment: Tick the 'multiline' checkbox.

Comment: You don't need to put `\s` and `\S` inside brackets.

Comment: Do either of you know why my regex with the lookbehind wasn't working?

Answer (score 3):

Try this regular expression

```
^(\s*.*?\s).*
```

Demo: [gskinner](http://regexr.com?34o72)

Comment: This one works, but it unfortunately grabs the space after the word as well. I'd prefer to just swap out everything up to and including the end of the word.

Comment: @LukeUnderwood in that case you can move the last `\s` out of the group ex `^(\s*.*?)\s.*` http://regexr.com?34o75

Comment: I had to take off the trailing asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, well this seems to work using `replace()` in Javascript:

```
/^([\s]*[\S]+).*$/
```

I tested it on [www.altastic.com/regexinator](http://altastic.com/regexinator/), which as far as I know is accurate [I made it though, so it may not be ;-) ]

Answer (score 0):

remove the first two words
@"^.asterisk? .asterisk? "
this works for me

when posted, the asterisk sign doesn't show. have no idea.

if you want to remove the first word, simply start the regex as follow
a dot sign
an asterisk sign
a question mark
a space
replace with ""